# HTML5 Cordova App Blob problems on Blackberry Z10 Android

Tags: android, html, blackberry, ionic-framework, blob

I have a very hard problem :-(
I try to deploy an Android App based on Ionic and Cordova. The App takes a picture and upload it to a server, sounds easy.
BUT on Blackberrys Z10 Android I got a Problem creating the Blob for Uploading :-(

Code Snippets

```
    var imgBlob = $helper.createBlob(this.result, "image/jpeg");
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('photo', imgBlob, file.name);
    fd.append('attachedData', attachedData);
    BaasBox.uploadFile(fd).done(function (result) {}
```

$helper.createBlob is like

```
self.createBlob = function(data, datatype)
      {
        var out;

        try {
          out = new Blob([data], {type: datatype});
          console.debug("case 1");
        }
        catch (e) {
          window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
            window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
            window.MozBlobBuilder ||
            window.MSBlobBuilder;

          if (e.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder) {
            var bb = new BlobBuilder();
            bb.append(data);
            out = bb.getBlob(datatype);
            console.debug("case 2");
          }
          else if (e.name == "InvalidStateError") {
            // InvalidStateError (tested on FF13 WinXP)
            out = new Blob([data], {type: datatype});
            console.debug("case 3");
          }
          else {
            // We're screwed, blob constructor unsupported entirely
            console.debug("Errore");
          }
        }
        return out;
      }
```

I have no idea how I can solve this ... :-(

regards
Meex